# Управление статикой из Django admin

Tags: django

Здравствуйте.

Буквально пару часов изучаю Django, до этого неплохо разобрался во Flask.

Интересует, возможно ли управлять статикой из админки Django, так, как это реализовано во [Flask-admin](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_fileadmin/)
То есть, чтобы прямо из админ панели можно было получить доступ к html/css/js файлам ?

Я понимаю, что это плохая идея с точки зрения безопасности приложения, тем не менее, необходимость таковая есть.

Заранее спасибо.

Прошу прощения за банальный вопрос.
Гуглил на 3х языках, ничего не нашёл :)

Comment: Вряд ли есть готовое решение, потому что это вредно и не нужно)

Comment: В стандартной, джанговской, админке ничего такого нету.

Comment: Не обязательно в стандартной. Возможно какие-то расширения, которые позволяют это делать.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Django строго следует идеям безопасности. Стандартная "админка" предназначена исключительно для добавления пользователей и разграничения уровней доступа. Руками можно "допереписать" все что угодно, но для управления html есть свой встроенный шаблонизатор с наследованием и прочими плюшками. Попробуйте использовать его для ваших задач.